# Why can't I assign default to my notnull generic type?

Tags: c#, generics, default, .net-6.0, notnull

Consider this class

```
public sealed record IdValuePair<TId, TValue>
{
    public IdValuePair(TId id, TValue value)
    {
        EnsureArg.HasValue(value, nameof(value));

        Id = id;
        Value = value;
    }

    public IdValuePair(TValue value)
    {
        EnsureArg.HasValue(value, nameof(value));

        Id = default!;
        Value = value;
    }

    public TId Id { get; }
    public TValue Value { get; }
}
```

Why is it that if I add the generic constraint

```
where TId : notnull
```

I am unable to do this assignment, due to the below error:

```
Id = default;
```

> CS8601   Possible null reference assignment.

Doesn't the `notnull` constraint ensure that `TId` is not null?

Comment: `where TId : notnull` promises that any properties of type `TId` will not be null. However, you're setting `Id` (which is of type `TId`) to `null`. So you're getting a warning, because you're violating the `notnull` constraint

Comment: Also, if TId is (at runtime) a reference type (as an example) - the default value is null https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values

Comment: @canton7 but I get the error even without `notnull` constraint - if I exclude the `!` when setting to `default`

Comment: @Bassie Because someone could create e.g. an `IdValuePair<string, string>`, where `TId` is a non-nullable string. So assigning `null` to it results in a warning. If you want the `Id` property to be nullable even if `TId` is a non-nullable type, then declare it as `public TId? Id { get; }`

Comment: @canton7 I want to ensure it is not null, so I have just left it as `= default!;`, but just seemed weird to me that I had to do it that way. Other option was to constrain with `: struct`

Comment: @Bassie What do you mean, ensure that it is not null? You explicitly set it to null yourself!

Comment: @canton7 well I'm setting it to `default`, which is not always null in fact it never will be in my use cases where it will almost always be `int` or `Guid` (so `0` or `00000-0000...`)

Comment: @Bassie But what if someone creates an `IdValuePair<string, string>`, where the Id is a `string`? They're allowed to do that, and you're seeing the `Id` property to `null` in that case.

Comment: @canton7 ye, its a problem, which is why I wanted to add `notnull` constraint

Comment: That's not what the `notnull` constraint does. And even so, you're missing the point: constraining `Id` to be a non-nullable *type* (such as `string`, rather than `string?`), but still assigning `null` to it in your constructor, still gives your problem. I think either: 1) constrain `TId` to be a value type, then it can't be null, or 2) make `Id` a `TId?` -- that means, if `TId` is a reference type then it can be null; if it's a value type the `?` has no effect

Comment: Thanks canton, I will probably just include a `EnsureArg.HasValue(id, nameof(id));` in my top ctor

Comment: @Bassie That still doesn't help, since your other constructor will create `IdValuePair` instances with a null `Id` property, and yet the signature of your `Id` promises that this can't happen

Comment: @canton7 as long as the value is considered as `default` then it is fine for my case - whether that `default` is `null` or `0` or whatever

Comment: @Bassie If your `Id` property can hold `default(TId)`, then it should be declared as `TId? Id { get; }`. That's what the question mark means (when applied to an unconstrained generic type). `TId?` means "can contain `default(TId)`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `IdValuePair<string, int>`, the default value for string is `null`. So assigning null to the Id would clearly be illegal, since you promised that it should not be null.

Adding the constraint `where TId : notnull` constraint would only prevent declarations like `IdValuePair<string?, int>`. So we would go from a "*Possible* null reference assignment" to a "*Definite* null reference assignment".

There is, as far as I know, no [generic constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) that restricts a type to either a nullable reference or nullable struct. And this can cause problems in some generic code.

There are a few possible options:

1. use a struct-constraint. Value types can never be null, so assigning default should be perfectly safe.
2. Use a new-constraint, and create a new object rather than using `default`
3. Create your own `Maybe<T> / Option<T> / Nullable<T>` type.